# Undoing a commit in Tortoisesvn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I did a search it said to view the log, right click the revision I want to go back to and select revert to this revision but I always get this error:

> Cannot reverse-merge a range from a
>   path's own future history; try
>   updating first

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to `Update` your working copy first.  You will then be able to revert the revision.

Comment: I've tried committing my files, it says there's nothing to commit

Comment: You need to Update to the HEAD of the repository. When you commit, it only updates the revision number in your working copy for the files that are committed. Directories also have version info in the working copy which can get out of date. Updating will bring all the directories up to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing an update (on your checked out copy) first?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot undo a commit in the sense of completely removing it from the repository.

What you can do is to get the state before the commit, and check that in as the current state. This is probably what you found in your search, and what Ben Lings's answer refers to.

Other than that, Ben Lings is correct. Update your working copy, then retrieve the old version (that is the "revers-merge" part), then commit that.

Comment: yeah thats fine but like I said, it doesn't work. I committed my copy and it still gives me the same error.